# Show differences between two Git branches by file extension

Tags: git, grep, git-bash

How can I list the differences between two git branches, but only show a those files with a certain file extension?

I've found that the following gets me all of the differing files between the two branches:-

```
git diff -r --name-only --no-commit-id branch1 branch2
```

But then I've tried to pipe this into grep and search for just 'yml' files....and I get nothing.

```
(git diff -r --name-only --no-commit-id branch1 branch2) | grep "*.yml"
```

I can see yml files output in the first command, but nothing in the second.

- Should I not be using grep?
- Is my grep command missing something?
- Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*.yml` is not a valid regular expression.

`*` means "the preceding character, zero or more times", so it doesn't make sense as the leading character of a regular expression.  If you want to find all files ending with `.yml`, just `... | grep '\.yml$'`.  we're escaping the `.` because `.` means "any character", and `$` means "end of the line" (so this would explicitly *not* match a file named, e.g., `foo.yml.j2`).

Answer (score 2):

You can append a shell-like pattern for git diff.

```
git diff -r --name-only --no-commit-id branch1 branch2 "*.yml"
```

As @larsks said, grep accepts regular expression, which is different from shell wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` accepts regular expression, where `*` and `.` have quite different meanings.

And yes, you did not have to use grep:

```
git diff -r --name-only --no-commit-id branch1 branch2 -- "*.yml"
```